# Safety tips to run services in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I want to understand a few things about services in Android, its a fact that a service running in background take more memory, right?. But few messaging services like Whatsapp, Facebook, etc , run always in background?. Even if we dont do operation also battery consumption will be more?

From the official [documentation by Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), to keep services run in background continues use **START_STICKY** flag & also start the services by implementing `IntentService` (To keep away from UI thread). If my service is dead due to heavy memory usage or by some unavoidable reason by android system, how to restart it?.

Also, if my activity is running toast displays fine, but if I kill my application through task manager, no toast appears & how do I check my service is running or dead?.

Answer (score 1):

Just use START_STICKY and it will be restarted later when memory is available.
`START_STICKY` tells the android to recreate the service after it has enough memory and call onStartCommand() with a null intent. 
Whereas `START_NOT_STICKY` tells the OS to not bother recreating the service again.

Use this method to check if your sevice is running or not:

```
public boolean isMyServiceRunning(Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        int i = 0;
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Byte.MAX_VALUE)) {
            i++;
            Log.v("ranjith", "value of i" + i);
            if ("com.ranjith.tempprod.CallDetectService".equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

`"com.ranjith.tempprod.CallDetectService"` here is a service name from my app, just replace with the service name you want to check.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer +1 for the help,  So should i start the service with IntentService or simply by inheriting the service?

Comment: You should use service if you have a long running task and don't want it to stop until you ask it to stop using stopSelf() whereas IntentService will stop after all its task is completed you need not stop it manually. I think you are looking for something that runs until you want to stop it.

Comment: HI, i want to get notifications once the call log changes, i have written a content observer in a service, so whenever call log changes i get notification. so in this case i can write it in simple service itself right no need to go for intentservices?